# Octave: Changing C Compiler for mkoctfile

Tags: octave

Is there a way to choose which compiler Octave uses when compiling mex files? In Matlab it would simply be:

`mex -setup c`

Comment: should be as easy as setting CXX and/or CC environment variables. Try >> setenv ("CXX", "foobar")